# Any tips on how I remove this white margin from my time picker on API Level 19?

Tags: java, android, xml

My time picker image link

[image]

Any tips on how I remove this white margin from my time picker in Android API 19?

I made my time picker background white and my RelativeLayout background blue.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TimePicker
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/timePicker"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: once check to give background color transparant

Comment: It is not limited to API 19, it will happen above 19 as well, and I think you cannot remove that.

Comment: change this in your time picker   hope it helps  android:background="@null"

Comment: @polaalper thanks, it worked. It makes it a bit hard to read tho.maybe Il try to add a custom white square at the back of the timepicker so i can read it. :p